# Freemarker - <#if ??> doesn't seem to work in identifying null objects

Tags: java, xml, freemarker, smooks

I am trying XML-XML transformations using FreeMarker. 
What is the correct way to handle null objects. (Not values but null objects)

When "AlertIndicator" tag is not present in the input XML, how can i handle it.
I tried all these combinations, but none seem to work :(

```
 <#if Response.Variables.AlertIndicator??>${Response.Variables.AlertIndicator}<#else></#if>
<#if (Response.Variables.AlertIndicator)??>${Response.Variables.AlertIndicator}<#else></#if>

${Response.Variables.AlertIndicator!""}
 ${(Response.Variables.AlertIndicator)!""}
```

All of these give me an exception

```
Expected a string or something automatically convertible to string (number, date or boolean), but this evaluated to a sequence+hash
Tip: This XML query result can't be used as string because for that it had to contain exactly 1 XML node, but it contains 0 nodes
```

The only thing that seems to be is "has_content" but it takes twice as long to process which is a big NO for my application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of a DOM query is always a list of nodes, even if possibly a 0-length list. The result node list itself always exists, so `Response.Variables.AlertIndicator??` is always `true`. (This also means that that query will work the same if there are no `Variables` and if there are no `AltertIndicators`, i.e., you can chain the steps safely.) So you have to check if the 1st node in the result list exists: `Response.Variables.AlertIndicator[0]??`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `?size` which will be greater than `0` when the tag exists:

```
<#if Response.Variables.AlertIndicator?size gt 0>${Response.Variables.AlertIndicator}</#if>
```

Not sure if it will be faster than `?has_content` though, you will need to check and if not, optimize it in a different way. Assigning to a variable before checking is a simple optimization.

```
<#assign x=Response.Variables.AlertIndicator>
<#if x?size gt 0>${x}</#if>
```